# Angular2 routerLinkActive not updating instantly upon loading large DOM

Tags: angular, dom, router

I have a sidebar where I choose from a list of Heroes. Each hero has an id and clicking just changes the route param (e.g.: /hero/id). I use routerLink and routerLinkActive to change the color of the active item.

For some heroes, I have a lot of rows in the table in my component so the DOM is slow to update when I navigate to its id. The problem that I'm facing now is that when I click on this hero item in the sidebar, the selection color for the new item does not change instantly.

I think it is because the DOM has not updated for the table component, and consequently the view for the entire app (including the sidebar) doesn't update.

Is there any way I can force the sidebar view to update first and then update the view of the table? Ideally I would show a spinner in the table component as soon as a new item is clicked, and then it would update once the DOM for the large table loads.

**** Adding code:

Sidebar template:

```
<ul *ngFor="hero of heroes">
    <li routerLink="heroes/{{hero.id}}" routerLinkActive="active">
</ul>
```

Hero component:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
   updateData(params.get(id)) //This takes some time to update the DOM as content is large
}
```

Comment: Show us some code to help you.

Comment: @Luillyfe sure, done

Comment: Is your `updateData(...)` method doing a web request to get the data or is it grabbed from a cache instead? How large of a table are we talking about?

Comment: It fetches data from cache. The table has several hundred rows with several styles and the load time is about 2 seconds for the DOM to update.